# Changing the ASP.NET XHTML Rendering Mode

Tags: asp.net, html

I'm using html provided by a designer to create a master page.

The html doctype is set to be HTML 4.0 Strict. The meta tags in the html do not have closing end tags (they end with > rather than />) and this html is compliant using the W3 validator tool.

For example:

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" >`

However, ASP.NET changes the head attributes before rendering the page and modifies the end tags, as below

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`

Now the addition of the /> at the end of the tag causes errors in the W3 validator.

How do I prevent this from happening, and ensure the html rendered is as the designers intended?

Comment: Ask them to do their job right... and deliver correct HTML. I am serious, even when you could edit the HTML what's going to happen the next time they update the design? your work will be overridden and you will have to do it again... potentially crashing their design... it's better to ask them politely to fix the HTML

Comment: The html provided validates according to W3 standards. The problem is ASP.NET unfortunately changing the output.

Comment: Just change your DOCTYPE in ASP.NET to the one you want if you don't like it

Comment: Thanks for the comments. It's not a simple case to change the doctype or the design. The simplest would be to change asp.net's behaviour but from what I can tell that's not possible.

Comment: Try to remove the runat="server" section of the head element to see if it works correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change how ASP.NET renders HTML by forcing it to use a particular XHTML conformance rendering mode.  I'm not sure what other side effects changing the renderer may have on the HTML output produced by ASP.NET.  This can be set in the web.config with the following.

```
<system.web>
    <!-- other elements here -->
    <xhtmlConformance 
        mode="Legacy" />
</system.web>
```

There are other caveats to using the "Legacy" rendering mode, see the following MSDN resources for other rendering modes and details.

[XHTML Standards in Visual Studio and ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exc57y7e.aspx)

[How to: Configure XHTML Rendering in ASP.NET Web Sites](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178159.aspx)